# addClass to link after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, addclass

i have some problems.
I am using drupal views exposed filters, and it sorts content by ajax calls.
That means i click 'Sort by name', and content below sorts without page refresh.
Than i decided to add special class to active sort link.

```
$(document).on('click', '.form-item-sort-bef-combine', function(){
$(this).addClass('selected-link');
});
```

it works as it should work, but when i click on link, class is added for a sec, and then disappear after ajax refresh. Seems that $(this) stop working after ajax.
Any ideas?

Comment: It should not remove the class. Can you update the JS code in the question and include the `ajax` call?

Comment: did you change  your HTML content with ajax? so may be you rewrited that item?

Comment: Could you provide the ajax function ?

Comment: I do not know how to give it to you. I have dynamically changing content, ajax function is provided by views-module 'use ajax on page' feature. It works like it should, but links waste their classes after the call. Here is structure:

Comment: <div class="views-widget">
<div class="bef-sort-combined bef-select-as-radios">
<div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-sort-bef-combine">
<label for="edit-sort-bef-combine">Сортировать по </label>
<div id="edit-sort-bef-combine" class="form-radios">
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-sort-bef-combine">
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-sort-bef-combine">
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-sort-bef-combine">
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-sort-bef-combine">

form-item-sort-bef-combine - is the class of sort links

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.form-item-sort-bef-combine', function(){
    $('.form-item-sort-bef-combine').addClass('selected-link');
});
```

Maybe this will solve your problem

**EDITED**

```
var tmp;

$(document).on('click', '.form-item-sort-bef-combine', function(){
    tmp = $(this).attr('class');
});


$.ajax({
                url: 'url',
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,     
                success: function(data) {
                    ...
                },
                complete: function() { 
                   $('.' + tmp).addClass('selected-link');
                }
            });
```

Comment: no legit. After ajax call all classes still disappear.

Comment: what does this ajax call do? Can you set function complete in ajax body and put code below there? See edited answer please

Comment: i havent written ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have mentioned, I think we might need more info to try to figure out what's going on.

I haven't really used jQuery much after switching to plain NativeJS.. But I feel like something like this MIGHT work?

```
$('body').on('click', '.form-item-sort-bef-combine', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected-link');
});
```

Instead of $('body'), you can maybe try a parent selector, like $('#form-wrapper'), or whatever you might have in your code.

Your code looks correct.. but *maybe* $(document) doesn't work with in this context?

Hope this helps

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `done()` function provided by `$ajax` or in the `success()` function **after updating the DOM**.

Doing it inside the `done()` function your `ajax` function should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/whatever',
    success:function(data){
        //update your DOM here
    }
}).done(function(){
    //add your class here
    $(".form-item-sort-bef-combine").addClass('selected-link');
});
```